# Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, scrollbar

I want to customize a scrollbar with CSS.

I use this WebKit CSS code, which works well for Safari and Chrome:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 15px;
  height: 15px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece {
  background-color: #c2d2e4;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #0a4c95;
}
```

How can I do the same thing in Firefox?

I know I can easily do it using jQuery, but I would prefer to do it with pure CSS if it's doable.

Comment: Please share how you can do it using jQuery. I'm faced with the same problem but used CSS to fix it for Webkit. However, Firefox poses a problem that your jQuery solution may be able to help with.

Comment: I recommend using jscrollpane jQuery plugin.

Comment: There is an issue with jScrollPane in Firefox. jScrollPane works perfectly in Chrome but in Firefox you have an empty _system_ scrollbar to the right of the jScrollPane scrollbar. There should only be one scrollbar

Comment: Not true. If you have that, you did something wrong somewhere.

Comment: See my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7357203/custom-scrollbars/32424642#32424642

Comment: I would like to recommend [`fakescroll`](https://github.com/yairEO/fakescroll) - A vanilla-js tiny script for custom scrollbars

Comment: I added a solution overview:  https://stackoverflow.com/a/70909679/14824067 .  And why do so many use jquery ; )

Answer (score 288, accepted):

As of late 2018, there is now limited customization available in Firefox!

See these answers:

- https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101063/405015
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53739309/405015

And this for background info: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1460109

---

<strike>There's no Firefox equivalent to `::-webkit-scrollbar` and friends.</strike>

You'll have to stick with JavaScript.

Plenty of people would like this feature, see: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790

---

As far as JavaScript replacements go, you can try:

- https://github.com/mdbootstrap/perfect-scrollbar
- https://github.com/Grsmto/simplebar
- https://github.com/vitch/jScrollPane

Comment: Thank you, ThirtyDot. One question though: what about -moz-appearance:scrollbartrack-vertical - and other related CSS extensions? Perhaps they can be used in some way?

Comment: No. Unfortunately, none of the possible values for [`-moz-appearance`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/-moz-appearance) can help. `"The -moz-appearance CSS property is used in Gecko (Firefox) to display an element using a platform-native styling based on the operating system's theme."` - you'll just get a native scrollbar.

Comment: Just in case anyone reading this needs a practical solution, I ended up using jscrollpane jQuery plugin.

Comment: @Jeff: You can try https://github.com/noraesae/perfect-scrollbar or https://github.com/jnicol/trackpad-scroll-emulator. They may already have been mentioned.

Comment: The answer doesn't help to solve the problem. But you can find the solution here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25480565/how-can-i-create-custom-scrollbar-for-mozilla-firefox-with-css

Comment: Also, for anybody that likes to keep the browser's native scrolling dynamic, use https://github.com/Diokuz/baron, good library, far better than dicking around with jScrollPane.

Comment: @thephpdev There's a bug in the demo. If I scroll down all the way to the bottom and continue scrolling down, in order to scroll back up I have to scroll up the same amount I scrolled down after hitting the bottom. This happened on Chrome 65 if that means anything. Lmk if that made any sense.

Comment: @JacquesMathieu, I see what you mean. Though that is not Baron's fault, if I download the page and prevent baron from initialising, the bug still occurs. So it looks like Chrome it at fault here.

Comment: Also, it doesn't look like I had to scroll up the equivalent amount I'd scrolled down. It looks like it starts ignoring input from the mousewheel once the limit has been reached. It appears to set some kind of timeout, which is reset when mousewheel input is received, such that if you don't use the mousewheel for ~ 500ms, the lock is released. It also looks like moving the mouse away from the scrollable container, and back over again releases the lock, although that may just be the timeout.

Comment: This isn't even a bug. I believe this behaviour exists to stop the whole page from scrolling when the limit is reached in a scrollable element.

Comment: It also seems to behave this way somewhat inconsistently, also on Chrome 65.

Comment: @thephpdev interesting. I wonder if there is a way to disable/change this behavior, as it is something I would prefer not to happen. No need to investigate this though, as this is not a pressing issue for me at all.

Comment: @JacquesMathieu, well think about it. If you've got an instance of some WYSIWYG editor on a page, and you're typing out anything of reasonable length, imagine how annoying it'd be if when you scrolled to the top of the editor, it'd start scrolling the whole page up. I don't even notice the behaviour, it just feels right. And clearly you've never had an issue with it if you've only just noticed it now and thought it was a bug.

Comment: @thephpdev In that case, that would be the preferred behavior. However, I think I was referring to being able to change the timeout for the lock, as half a second seemed too long for me. Also, just tested this again and it works fine with no delay between scrolling down and up on Chrome 66.

Comment: @JacquesMathieu, I understand what you mean, when you do really want to scroll up in the cases where that lock occurs, it does feel disconcerting.

Also, just tested the demo (also on 66), and it appears they've disabled the functionality, but only if the scrollable container is not inside another scrollable container. If you add `margin-bottom: 2000px` to the `<body>` element so that the page becomes scrollable, the lock behaviour still exists. Though it does seem to be improved, although that may be placebo as I expected a change in behaviour.

Comment: https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scrollbars-1/ is the stage 1 start of the spec, but it's enabled in Firefox Nightly now out of the box by default.

Answer (score 128):

Firefox 64 adds support for the spec draft [CSS Scrollbars Module Level 1](https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scrollbars-1/), which adds [two new properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars) of [`scrollbar-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width) and [`scrollbar-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-color) which give some control over how scrollbars are displayed.

You can set [`scrollbar-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-color) to one of the following values (descriptions from MDN):

- `auto` Default platform rendering for the track portion of the scrollbar, in the absence of any other related scrollbar color properties.
- `<color>` `<color>` Applies the first color to the scrollbar thumb, the second to the scrollbar track.

Previously the spec included `dark` and `light` values that [were not implemented in Firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1492040). These values have since been removed from the spec.

On stock Android with mobile Firefox the thumb can be colored, but there is no track to color.

Additionally in macOS Firefox version prior to 99.0, the auto-hiding semi-transparent scrollbars that are the macOS default could not be styled by these rules. As of Firefox 99.0 all macOS scrollbar modes (configured under System Preferences > Show Scroll Bars) can be colored.

**Visual Demo:**

```css
.scroll {
  width: 20%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: inline-block;
}
.scroll-color-auto {
  scrollbar-color: auto;
}
.scroll-color-colors {
  scrollbar-color: orange lightyellow;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll scroll-color-auto">
  <p>auto</p><p>auto</p><p>auto</p><p>auto</p><p>auto</p><p>auto</p>
</div>

<div class="scroll scroll-color-colors">
  <p>colors</p><p>colors</p><p>colors</p><p>colors</p><p>colors</p><p>colors</p>
</div>
```

You can set [`scrollbar-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width) to one of the following values (descriptions from MDN):

- `auto` The default scrollbar width for the platform.
- `thin` A thin scrollbar width variant on platforms that provide that option, or a thinner scrollbar than the default platform scrollbar width.
- `none` No scrollbar shown, however the element will still be scrollable.

You can also set a specific length value, according to the spec. Both `thin` and a specific length may not do anything on all platforms, and what exactly it does is platform-specific. In particular, Firefox doesn't appear to be currently support a specific length value ([this comment on their bug tracker seems to confirm this](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1475033#c65)). The `thin` keywork does appear to be well-supported however, with macOS and Windows support at-least.

On stock Android with mobile Firefox the `auto` width thumb is already rather thin, and `thin` does not make it thinner.

It's probably worth noting that the length value option and the entire `scrollbar-width` property are being considered for removal in a future draft, and if that happens this particular property may be removed from Firefox in a future version.

**Visual Demo:**

```css
.scroll {
  width: 30%;
  height: 100px;
  border: 1px solid grey;
  overflow: scroll;
  display: inline-block;
}
.scroll-width-auto {
  scrollbar-width: auto;
}
.scroll-width-thin {
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}
.scroll-width-none {
  scrollbar-width: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="scroll scroll-width-auto">
<p>auto</p><p>auto</p><p>auto</p><p>auto</p><p>auto</p><p>auto</p>
</div>

<div class="scroll scroll-width-thin">
<p>thin</p><p>thin</p><p>thin</p><p>thin</p><p>thin</p><p>thin</p>
</div>

<div class="scroll scroll-width-none">
<p>none</p><p>none</p><p>none</p><p>none</p><p>none</p><p>none</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer. I've updated my accepted answer to promote this (and the other relevant answer) so that people are more likely to see it.

Comment: This essentially duplicates [Luca's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53739309/712334) from three weeks prior.

Comment: @JoshHabdas That answer does not contain nearly as much compatibility or usage information. I created this answer because the other answer didn't have the important information I was looking for.

Comment: You could give them credit, suggest feedback or consider editing their answer.

Comment: @JoshHabdas A radical edit like that would seem inappropriate. I also didn't use their answer to compose this answer, I first learned about it through the Firefox release notes, then later found this Q&A which didn't have any of the information I had researched.

Comment: I believe upvotes are based on usefulness, so no worries. You may chose not to credit or acknowledge their answer but I don't see much usefulness in duplicates, which this essentially is.

Comment: @JoshHabdas Well, 5 people already found it useful, and it contains information not found anywhere else on the web, so I disagree.

Comment: if they made `scrollbar-width: thin` why couldn't they make `scrollbar-width: thick`?

Comment: need to add the class to html tag not body tag for firefox (if u want thin scrollbar on body)

Comment: "The auto-hiding semi-transparent scrollbars that are the macOS default cannot be colored with this rule (they still choose their own contrasting color based on the background). Only the permanently showing scrollbars (System Preferences > Show Scroll Bars > Always) are colored." :facepalm:

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara I'm trying to understand how this works, when I look at your code snippet on FF, the scrollbar in the first container looks different from the second, there are no directional arrow buttons showing on hover. I'm currently trying to remove the FF scrollbar hover styles, doesn't show when not over, shows thin when over the container, but then if I hover over the scrollbar, there are more styles I can't seem to get to work on FF.

Comment: @Tyler How it works is browser and operating system dependent. You basically have two properties you can suggest, colors and width. What the browser does with is depends on the browser and how it customizes the scrollbars of the OS.

Answer (score 72):

Since [Firefox 64](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Firefox/Releases/64), is possible to use [new specs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars) for a simple Scrollbar styling (*not as complete as in Chrome with vendor prefixes*).

In [this example](https://jsfiddle.net/ldetomi/4Lt2ro5z/9/) is possible to see a solution that combine different rules to address both Firefox and Chrome with a similar (not equal) final result (example use your original Chrome rules):

The key rules are:

**For Firefox**

```
.scroller {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-color: #0A4C95 #C2D2E4;
}
```

**For Chrome**

```
.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
    height: 15px;
}

.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  {
    background-color: #C2D2E4;
}

.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #0A4C95;
}
```

Please note that respect to your solution, is possible to use also simpler Chrome rules as the following:

```
.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-track  {
    background-color: #C2D2E4;
}

.scroller::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    height: 30px;
    background-color: #0A4C95;
}
```

Finally, in order to hide arrows in scrollbars also in Firefox, currently is necessary to set it as "*thin*" with the following rule `scrollbar-width: thin;`

Comment: Looks like IE 5.5 may have gotten something right after all. :)

Answer (score 44):

May I offer an alternative?

No scripting whatsoever, only standardized css styles and a little bit of creativity. Short answer - masking parts of the existing browser scrollbar, which means you retain all of it's functionality.

```
.scroll_content {
    position: relative;
    width: 400px;
    height: 414px;
    top: -17px;
    padding: 20px 10px 20px 10px;
    overflow-y: auto;
}
```

For demo and a little bit more in-depth explanation, check here...

[jsfiddle.net/aj7bxtjz/1/](http://jsfiddle.net/aj7bxtjz/1)

Comment: This doesn't answer the question, unfortunately. Dimitri is trying to style the scrollbar, not hide it.

Comment: That was 4 years ago (I'm aware of that) so I'm sure he already did something by now. But the topic is still relevant today - while other browsers allow some type of "illegal" modification of scrollbars, FF doesn't. That's why I decided to post it.And the front-end result is visually styling scrollbar, regardless of the fact that the way to do it is hiding part of it.

Comment: i love this solution except for all the extra markup with absolute positioning (makes variable size stuff a nightmare) plus you cannot actually change the style, you are simply masking/hiding elements of the existing scroller - too bad if i want a green bar!

Comment: yea, after four years, it's not about answering the OP's question as much as it is contributing to the community.

Comment: The essence of the problem is that the solutions provided by some rendering engines are non-standard. This is the question that best addresses my concerns and this is the answer I was scrolling for.

Comment: This is unfortunately a fickle solution as you have hard-coded the size of the size of the scrollbar—and that can change based on accessibility settings among other reasons.

Answer (score 40):

Year 2020 this works

```
/* Thin Scrollbar */
:root{
  scrollbar-color: rgb(210,210,210) rgb(46,54,69) !important;
  scrollbar-width: thin !important;
}
```

https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomCSSforFx/issues/160

Comment: Good news, but how can we change the outline?

Comment: This Works on Wordpress Guys, Thanks <3

Answer (score 36):

I thought I would share my findings in case someone is considering a jQuery plugin to do the job.

I gave [jQuery Custom Scrollbar](http://manos.malihu.gr/tuts/jquery_custom_scrollbar.html) a go. It's pretty fancy and does some smooth scrolling (with scrolling inertia) and has loads of parameters you can tweak, but it ended up being a bit too CPU intensive for me (and it adds a fair amount to the DOM).

Now I'm giving [Perfect Scrollbar](http://utatti.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/) a go. It's simple and lightweight (6 KB) and it's doing a decent job so far. It's not CPU intensive at all (as far as I can tell) and adds very little to your DOM. It's only got a couple of parameters to tweak (wheelSpeed and wheelPropagation), but it's all I need and it handles updates to the scrolling content nicely (such as loading images).

P.S. I did have a quick look at JScrollPane, but @simone is right, it's a bit dated now and a PITA.

Comment: There's also [trackpad scroll emulator](https://github.com/jnicol/trackpad-scroll-emulator) -- it's what twitch.tv uses.

Comment: Perfect Scrollbar is actually really good. After exhausting many other options, I found it to be the best solution. Thanks for suggesting it.

Comment: nanoScroller is also really good, and relatively lean.
https://jamesflorentino.github.io/nanoScrollerJS/
Opposed to the heavy JS plugins, this one simply hides the native scroller, and shows an alternate scroller using the native 'scroll' event

Comment: i've been avoiding all of the jquery solutions, since they *all* lag out on slower machines or machines under stress, but PS looks like a winner

Answer (score 9):

## Year 2022

**Tested with the latest Firefox and Chrome versions**

The following snippet will display the *same scrollbar styles* on Chrome and Firefox, try it out.

```css
html {
  /* For Firefox */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-color: #008de4 #0d3b97;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

/* For Chrome and other browsers except Firefox */
body::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 0.5em;
    background-color: #0d3b97;
}
body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #008de4;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body style="height: 600px"></body>
</html>
```

You can also customize the scrollbar track using the following (but it will not work for Firefox)

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track
```

Comment: But still there are few things which needs improvement from firefox side. Like, When you have the overflow content, scrollbar is coming inside the control. this effects the inner elements width, where as in chrome the control size will be unaltered and the scrollbar will get added at the edge of control.

Answer (score 6):

As of now, 2021, there are just two properties for Firefox scrollbar customization available; `scrollbar-color` and `scrollbar width`.

```css
scrollbar-color: red yellow; /* track thumb */
scrollbar-width: 5px; /* none, thin, or auto */
```

```css
.demo {
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

.demo {
  scrollbar-color: red yellow;
  scrollbar-width: 10px;
}
```

```html
<div class="demo">
  <p>
    some scroll text...<br><br> don't you dare scroll to the bottom...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some
    scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> still here? fair warning, do
    NOT scroll farther down!<br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> STOP!
    <br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> NOW I'M MAD<br><br> some
    scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> AND THAT IS GENERALLY A BAD IDEA<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> bye
    <br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    last last last warning; you will not like what is at the bottom<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll
    text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> thare is nothing at the bottom!<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br>    some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> some scroll text...<br><br> NOTHING >:D
  </p>
</div>
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="demo">
```

**CSS**

```
.demo {
    overflow-y: scroll;
}

.demo {
    scrollbar-color: red yellow;
    scrollbar-width: 5px;
}
```

Comment: `scrollbar-width` only supports 3 values: `none`, `thin` and `auto` - https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width

Comment: the right order is  (thumb , track) not (track,thumb)

Comment: And the position of scrollbar inside element effects the inner elements width.it will take 15px when scrollbar presents. This makes inner elements width related styles inconsistent when we set the overflow to auto.  :(

Answer (score 6):

Here I have tried this CSS for all major browser & tested: Custom color are working fine on scrollbar.

Yes, there are limitations on several versions of different browsers.

```css
/* Only Chrome */
html::-webkit-scrollbar {width: 17px;}
html::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background-color: #0064a7; background-clip: padding-box; border: 1px solid #8ea5b5;}
html::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background-color: #8ea5b5; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {background-color: #8ea5b5;}
/* Only IE */
html {scrollbar-face-color: #0064a7; scrollbar-shadow-color: #8ea5b5; scrollbar-highlight-color: #8ea5b5;}
/* Only FireFox */
html {scrollbar-color: #0064a7 #8ea5b5;}
/* View Scrollbar */
html {overflow-y: scroll;overflow-x: hidden;}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
</head>
<body>
    <header>
        <div id="logo"><img src="/logo.png">HTML5&nbsp;Layout</div>
        <nav>  
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a>
                <li><a href="https://html-css-js.com/">HTML</a>
                <li><a href="https://html-css-js.com/css/code/">CSS</a>
                <li><a href="https://htmlcheatsheet.com/js/">JS</a>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </header>
    <section>
        <strong>Demonstration of a simple page layout using HTML5 tags: header, nav, section, main, article, aside, footer, address.</strong>
    </section>
    <section id="pageContent">
        <main role="main">
            <article>
                <h2>Stet facilis ius te</h2>
                <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, nonumes voluptatum mel ea, cu case ceteros cum. Novum commodo malorum vix ut. Dolores consequuntur in ius, sale electram dissentiunt quo te. Cu duo omnes invidunt, eos eu mucius fabellas. Stet facilis ius te, quando voluptatibus eos in. Ad vix mundi alterum, integre urbanitas intellegam vix in.</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Illud mollis moderatius</h2>
                <p>Eum facete intellegat ei, ut mazim melius usu. Has elit simul primis ne, regione minimum id cum. Sea deleniti dissentiet ea. Illud mollis moderatius ut per, at qui ubique populo. Eum ad cibo legimus, vim ei quidam fastidii.</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>Ex ignota epicurei quo</h2>
                <p>Quo debet vivendo ex. Qui ut admodum senserit partiendo. Id adipiscing disputando eam, sea id magna pertinax concludaturque. Ex ignota epicurei quo, his ex doctus delenit fabellas, erat timeam cotidieque sit in. Vel eu soleat voluptatibus, cum cu exerci mediocritatem. Malis legere at per, has brute putant animal et, in consul utamur usu.</p>
            </article>
            <article>
                <h2>His at autem inani volutpat</h2>
                <p>Te has amet modo perfecto, te eum mucius conclusionemque, mel te erat deterruisset. Duo ceteros phaedrum id, ornatus postulant in sea. His at autem inani volutpat. Tollit possit in pri, platonem persecuti ad vix, vel nisl albucius gloriatur no.</p>
            </article>
        </main>
        <aside>
            <div>Sidebar 1</div>
            <div>Sidebar 2</div>
            <div>Sidebar 3</div>
        </aside>
    </section>
    <footer>
        <p>&copy; You can copy, edit and publish this template but please leave a link to our website | <a href="https://html5-templates.com/" target="_blank" rel="nofollow">HTML5 Templates</a></p>
        <address>
            Contact: <a href="mailto:me@example.com">Mail me</a>
        </address>
    </footer>


</body>

</html>
```

Keyword values
scrollbar-width: auto|thin|none;

Global values
scrollbar-width: inherit|initial|revert|revert-layer;
scrollbar-width: unset;

Firefox 84 was released on December 15, 2020. Removed Properties are as follows:

Removed proprietary -moz-default-appearance property values scrollbar-small (scrollbar-width: thin is used instead) and scrollbar (macOS only; scrollbar-horizontal and scrollbar-vertical are used instead) ([bug 1673132](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1654956)).

Answer (score 2):

This feature is heavily experimental and I guess Mozilla has a lot to do until it becomes usable for everyone on every page. I have tested many solutions but the following code is working perfectly.

**CSS**

```
:root {
  scrollbar-color: #333333 #999999 !important;
  scrollbar-width: thin !important;
}
```

**OR**

```
#ClassName {
  scrollbar-color: #333333 #999999 !important;
  scrollbar-width: thin !important;
}
```

**Reference:**
[LINK 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox/54101063#answer-60224816)
[LINK 2](https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomCSSforFx/issues/160)

Answer (score 2):

Firefox only accepts:

```
scrollbar-color: #F8F8F8 // Add your color
scroll-bar-width: thin/auto/none
```

Answer (score 2):

2021

Firefox

```
.nav{
scrollbar-width: 0px;
scrollbar-width: none;}
```

Chrome

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  height: 0;  /* Remove scrollbar space */
  background: transparent;  
/* Optional: just make scrollbar invisible */
}
```

for vertical and horizontal scrollbar change the width or height attribute

Answer (score 2):

The short answer:

## Only the following work(s)

in firefox *(as of JAN 2022)*:

:

| property (not pseudo element!) |  | allowed values |
| --- | --- | --- |
| `scrollbar-width` |  | `thin` (actually very thin) |
|  |  | `auto` (standard thick version) |
|  |  | `none` (hides the scrollbar) |
| `scrollbar-color` |  | `color color` |

:

You have to set both color values, **first scrollbar thumb** , **second the scrollbar background**.
**It takes any normal color values**, using names like "black", hex-values like "#000000", functions like "rgb(0,0,0) as well as variables like "var(--previouslydefinedblack)".
BUT it **does not take linear gradients** as input, neither normally nor via css variable.
The order of the properties is unimportant by the way.

Comment: For the standard scrollbar use these via the html selector.
And please comment in case sth changes.

Comment: (offtopic: in chrome it still works like this btw: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar and bear in mind that https://stackoverflow.com/a/67902128/14824067 )

Comment: Both "thin" and "auto" render exactly the same way in Firefox; a thin 1 or 2 pixels wide scrollbar.

Comment: @DavidMartins Can be :/ ( - I didn't try this in a whole while - I'd wish they'd just enable a few more possibilities with firefox anyways :) ).

Answer (score 0):

It works in user-style, and it seems not to work in web pages. I have not found official direction from Mozilla on this. While it may have worked at some point, Firefox does not have official support for this. This bug is still open https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790

```
scrollbar {
/*  clear useragent default style*/
   -moz-appearance: none !important;
}
/* buttons at two ends */
scrollbarbutton {
   -moz-appearance: none !important;
}
/* the sliding part*/
thumb{
   -moz-appearance: none !important;
}
scrollcorner {
   -moz-appearance: none !important;
   resize:both;
}
/* vertical or horizontal */
scrollbar[orient="vertical"] {
    color:silver;
}
```

check http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/  for details.

Comment: i tried as same as you written, but its not working for my in FF, check the http://jsfiddle.net/gGbkY/1/  am i missing something ?

Comment: It works in user-style, and it seems not to work in web pages.  I have not found official direction from Mozilla on this.

Comment: please check out the same link: it doesn't work any more

Comment: What's the user-style?

Comment: The bug you linked was reported 17 years ago and still hasn't been assigned. I think it's safe to say that FF will never support the hiding of native scrollbars.

Answer (score 0):

This Works on Wordpress Guys Custom CSS

```
/* Fire-Fox Scrollbar */
:root{
  scrollbar-face-color: rgb(176, 88, 54); /* Firefox 63 compatibility */
  scrollbar-track-color: rgb(51, 62, 72); /* Firefox 63 compatibility */
  scrollbar-color: rgb(176, 88, 54) rgb(51, 62, 72);
  scrollbar-width: auto;
}
```

Ref: https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomCSSforFx/issues/160

Answer (score 0):

```
.mat-tab-header {
   overflow-x: scroll !important;
   // For Firefox
   scrollbar-color: transparent transparent;
   border-bottom: none; 
}
    
.mat-tab-header::-webkit-scrollbar { // TO Remove horizontal scrollbar in tabs
   display: none !important;
}
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

My solution: add for other browsers what you want, and for firefox add:

```
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
    div {
        scrollbar-width: thin;
    }
}
```

This is conditioned. So affects only firefox. It makes the scrollbar thin.

Answer (score 0):

As in 2024 scrollbar-color is applying also for chrome. To ensure a cross-browser solution, it's advisable to separate the styles for Firefox using the @-moz-document rule.

```css
@-moz-document url-prefix() {
  * {
    scrollbar-color: green white;
  }
}

::-webkit-scrollbar,
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 14px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track,
*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background-color: white;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb,
*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  border-radius: 8px;
  background-color: red;
  border: 4px solid red;
}
```

```html
<div style="overflow: scroll; width: 200px; height: 150px;">
  <span style="color: green;">GREEN</span> scrollbar in Firefox, <span style="color: red">RED</span> scrollbar in Chrome. 
<div style="color: #ccc;">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Sed euismod, justo at tincidunt aliquet, nunc nisl lacinia nunc, vel tincidunt nisl mauris id nunc. Nullam euismod, nunc a lacinia ultrices, nisl nisl aliquam justo, nec tincidunt nunc nisl id nunc.
  Sed euismod, justo at tincidunt aliquet, nunc nisl lacinia nunc, vel tincidunt nisl mauris id nunc. Nullam euismod, nunc a lacinia ultrices, nisl nisl aliquam justo, nec tincidunt nunc nisl id nunc.</div>
</div>
```