# Styling scroll bars with CSS

Tags: css, scrollbar

I tried searching online but I didn't find any good sources on this. Is there a way to style scroll bars with pure CSS so that it is compatible with a maximum number of browsers?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can style scrollbars in [Internet Explorer](http://www.ssi-developer.net/css/scrollbar-colours.shtml) and [Webkit](http://www.webkit.org/blog/363/styling-scrollbars/) only.

Note that these are [not standard properties](http://www.w3.org/Style/Examples/007/scrollbars).

However, you can achieve this with JavaScript. One project that does this is [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/).

Comment: Filling in the blank, you can't do it in Firefox: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox/6165489#6165489

Comment: Is there any update on this seeing as were about a year on ?

Comment: @sam If you must have this, I'd use a custom control.

Answer (score 1):

Adding my 2 pence a little late, but if you really want to style them I would suggest trying http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/. It's not a pure CSS solution like you are looking for but is a solution of sorts.