# How to change scroll bar style or hide scroll bar in browser through javascript or css?

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar

Is there any way to change the default scroll bar style? or hide the scroll bar and enable to scroll?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Styling scroll bars with CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6171460/styling-scroll-bars-with-css)

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7725652/css-scrollbar-style-cross-browser

Answer (score 2):

For hide

```
body {
overflow:hidden;
```

}

change scroll bar in chrome and safari

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
```

}

```
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #bebebe; 
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
border-radius: 1px;
```

}

```
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
-webkit-border-radius: 1px;
border-radius: 1px;
background: #dcdcdc; 
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px #bebebe;
```

}

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:window-inactive {
background: bebebe;
```

}

Answer (score 1):

You can use jQuery plugins to customize the scroll bar

I recommend using [jScrollPane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)

It is easy to use.. and you can customize per your requirement

There are some other plugins also which might useful for you.. You can search over internet