# mimic this webkit css cross browser

Tags: html, css, webkit, cross-browser, scrollbar

I have this css to change the design of the scrollbar in webkit browsers. How can I replicate this, without javascript or jquery, in other browsers like IE or Firefox or Opera.

Thanks

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
border-radius: 10px;
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
}
```

Comment: I think It's only in Webkit and IE. It was a trend a couple years ago.

Comment: I like my scrollbars the way they are.

Comment: there s the answer to the same question:
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox

Comment: @bazmegakapa Yeah, a lot of people are against the idea of modifying scrollbars.It's been tried a while ago and personally, I like my scrollbars the way they are too. I ll use a Jquery plugin once in a while if a client wants it.

Comment: @Paquet If you need to use a custom Javascript scrollbar, use it if it really adds value, and does not take away any functionality. It might look better, but who cares, if it gives the user frustration when used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is in IE

http://www.jessett.com/web_sites/css/custom_scrollbars.shtml

Comment: @Bellamy Fortunately, styling scrollbars is not supported in those browsers.