# CSS3 scrollbar styling on a div

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

How can I style webkit scrollbars with CSS3?

I mean these properties:

```css
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}
                    
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}
                    
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Here is my div tag:

```html
<div class="scroll"></div>
```

Here is my current CSS:

```css
.scroll {
    width: 200px; height: 400px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
```

Comment: `overflow: hidden` hides any scrollbars, so there's nothing to decorate with CSS3. You have to make scrollbars visible with `overflow:scroll` or `overflow:auto`

Answer (score 149, accepted):

Setting `overflow: hidden` hides the scrollbar. Set `overflow: scroll` to make sure the scrollbar appears all the time.

To use the `::webkit-scrollbar` property, simply target `.scroll` before calling it.

```
.scroll {
   width: 200px;
   height: 400px;
    background: red;
   overflow: scroll;
}
.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
​
```

See this live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/KMzgm/)

Comment: Thanks this works. Is there a way we could do the same for mozilla browser?

Comment: Not without jQuery/JavaScript. See this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox

Comment: This scrollbar design is very nice, I used it in more than one project.

Answer (score 1):

You're setting `overflow: hidden`. This will hide anything that's too large for the `<div>`, meaning scrollbars won't be shown. Give your `<div>` an explicit width and/or height, and change `overflow` to `auto`:

```
.scroll {
   width: 200px;
   height: 400px;
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

If you only want to show a scrollbar if the content is longer than the `<div>`, change `overflow` to `overflow: auto`. You can also only show one scrollbar by using `overflow-y` or `overflow-x`.

Answer (score 1):

The problem with the css3 scroll bars is that, interaction can only be performed on the content. we can't interact with the scroll bar on touch devices.

Answer (score 0):

```
.scroll {
   width: 200px; height: 400px;
   overflow: auto;
}
```