# What is the best alternative to frames. I need 2 Windows on one screen that I can adjust the width on using a vertical slider like frames have

Tags: html, frames

I am writing a utility for myself and need content from two sites on the same page. I did it with
frames and the main reason I like frames is because it is easy to use the mouse to move the slider and make one page have a greater percentage then the other. See example below. I keep reading that you should not use frames, but I do not know of an alternative that offers the same vertical slider bar that frames does. Any suggestions or opinions would be appreciated.

```
<frameset cols='50%,50%'>
<frame src='test.php'>
<frame src='test2.php'>
</frameset>
```

Comment: Maybe this thread is useful for you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12337821/css3-scrollbar-styling-on-a-div.

Comment: I looked at the example in the link you posted, but it is nothing like a frame. I want the vertical bar that you can slide to the left or right to change the ratio of the two web pages.

Comment: You looked at the `See this live example`? That has vertical scroll bar based on content area.