# Scrollbar style in firefox?

Tags: html, firefox, css

In Opera and IE I can use scrollbar-face/arrow/track/shadow...-color cssvalues to change the scrollbar's appearance. In chrome/safari (webkit) there are ::-webkit-scrollbar ::-webkit-scrollbar-button ::-webkit-scrollbar-track etc... css values.

So in IE, Chrome, Opera and Safari I know how to customize the scrollbars. But how to manage it in firefox? Is there any way to customize the scrollbars in firefox using CSS?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/6165489/1947535).