# Scrollbar over content

Tags: css, webkit, scrollbar

I want to make transparent scrollbar that should be placed over div with content. **Only css and only webkit browsers**.
It must look like [example](http://lab.cubiq.org/iscroll/examples/simple/). My [code](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/uidwz). The problem is that scrollbar moves content to the left. How to make it look like in example? Thank you for replies.

```
div{
  width:410px;
  height:100px;
  overflow-y:scroll;
  border:1px solid green;
  position:relative;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar{
  width:20px;
  position:absolute;
  right:20px;
  z-index:100;
} 

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
  background-color:rgba(0,0,0,1);
  border-right:10px solid white;
}
```

Comment: You should include the code into your question and provide a link to a jsFiddle.net snippet.

Comment: you can't do this **Only css and only webkit browsers** ! you should be use `javascript` or `jquery`..

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

This is very similar to the example.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width:7px;
} 

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
    border-radius: 3px;
    border: 1px solid #fff;
}
```

otherwise you must use [iscroll plugin](http://iscrolljs.com/)