# scrollbar css in firefox and IE

Tags: html, css, internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox

I am trying to display the scrollbars in my application as same as mac scroll bar.For that with the below css I am able to display in safari and chrome.How to display this in IE and Firefox.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 8px; 

  background-color: rgba(0,0,0,0);
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
}
/* hover effect for both scrollbar area, and scrollbar 'thumb' */
::-webkit-scrollbar:hover {
  background-color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.09);
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
     Yes, I pulled out digital color meter */
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical:active {
  background: rgba(0,0,0,0.61); /* Some darker color when you click it */
  -webkit-border-radius: 100px;
}
```

Comment: This will help you: http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/

Comment: already answered http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox?lq=1