# how to change Extjs scrollbar width and border radius into firefox

Tags: css

How to change scrollbar width and border radius. I am using Extjs. I changed CSS of Chrome it works fine but when i open into Firefox, it gives his standard scrollbar. I need a help, please help to change the scrollbar  into Firefox.

i used a code following for chrome:

```
 ::-webkit-scrollbar-track{      
    } 
    ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width:12px;
    background:#ffffff;
    }
    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background:rgb(207,206,205);
    -webkit-border-radius: 3px;    


}
```

Answer (score 0):

[There is a bug on this topic](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790). There's no Gecko equivalent to ::-webkit-scrollbar. [See this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)

Comment: Thanks..bro..ok i have checked