# Is there a -moz equivalent of ::-webkit-scrollbar?

Tags: css

I have used `::-webkit-scrollbar` to hide scrollbars on an element in Safari/Chrome with the following CSS:

```
#element::-webkit-scrollbar { width:0 !important; height:0 !important }
```

Is there any way of accomplishing the same in Firefox?

Comment: This has been answered: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox

Answer (score 0):

If you just want to hide scrollbars, better use

```
overflow: hidden
```

Comment: I want to take advantage of the scrolling behavior, but have no visible scrollbars. This is working beautifully in webkit.