# Increase Scroll-bar width in Firefox - html / css

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, firefox

I saw some questions about this, but those questions don't gave a solution that could work for me.

I want to increase the **Scrollbar width** of a div. The div size is huge, so a horizontal scrollbar has appeared. Now I want to increase the width of that scrollbar for more flexibility.
So I search and found following link with code that works on Chrome browser.
[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2aHeE/)

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 2em;
    height: 2em
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {
    background: #ccc
}
```

But this doesn't work on Firefox. I tried to replace the **webkit** with **moz** , didn't work either.

I also found that writting following code in userContent.css file of firefox can increase scrollbar width, but 1) I didn't find that **userContent.css** file in windows 7. 2) I can't go to users' home to tell them how to increase scrollbar width manually :P That's not a solution.

```
/* Increase width of VERTICAL SCROLLBAR */
scrollbar[orient="vertical"], scrollbar[orient="vertical"] thumb, scrollbar[orient="vertical"] scrollbarbutton { min-width: 35px !important; -moz-appearance: none !important; }

/* Increase width of HORIZONTAL SCROLLBAR */
scrollbar[orient="horizontal"], scrollbar[orient="horizontal"] thumb, scrollbar[orient="horizontal"] scrollbarbutton { min-height: 35px !important; -moz-appearance: none !important; }
```

Is there any way so that I can increase scrollbar width in both Chrome & Firefox?? (Forget IE) I can use **html css javascript & jquery** solutions, **but no scrollbar plugin**. I've to convert the native scrollbar from browsers.

Comment: The answer is **you cannot**, so use some jQuery plugin

Comment: But "Everything is possible in this world"  WITHOUT EVEN JQUERY PLUGINS

Comment: You mean in Chrome EVERYTHING IS ALL RIGHT but not in Firefox?,So you want the same thing in Firefox also ?

Comment: Duplicate : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox/6165489#6165489

Comment: @PratikJoshi yes. I want to widen the scrollbar in FF

Comment: @airi Which part of this line you didn't understand? "I saw some questions about this, but those questions don't gave a solution that could work for me."

Comment: @AtanuCSE : btw this is the answer you seek : Unfortunately Firefox still doesnt support custom scrollbars.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Although chrome supports changing the scrollbar width using -webkit prefixes none of the other browsers do. Some allow the scrollbar to be styled so the colours are different but as far as I am aware you cannot change the width.

Instead, if it is absolutely essential you change the scrollbar, you will need to use a JavaScript solution.

There are many solutions out there - too many to document in an answer on SO - but here are a few links to get you started:

- http://slodive.com/web-development/jquery-scroll/
- http://designhuntr.com/custom-jquery-scrollers/
- http://www.bloggingehow.com/2012/11/top-10-jquery-scrollbar-plugins-with.html
- http://www.scratchinginfo.com/best-jquery-scrollbar-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

check the below link. check the philipp comment mentioned in the site.

https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/979461 also check the bugZilla

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790

Dont forget to check the comment #134

[Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)