# -webkit-scrollbar is not working on Firefox

Tags: google-chrome, firefox, scroll, scrollbar

Need help!

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar{ width: 0; }
```

Its working only on Google Chrome but does not work on Firfox.
how can I solve this please help me.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Increase Scroll-bar width in Firefox - html / css](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22243949/increase-scroll-bar-width-in-firefox-html-css)

Answer (score 4):

Just use [scrollbar-width](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width) property as a fallback for Firefox browser.

```
body {
    scrollbar-width: none; /* For Firefox */
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This worked for me

```
:root{
  scrollbar-face-color: rgb(210,210,210); /* Firefox 63 compatibility */
  scrollbar-track-color: rgb(46,54,69); /* Firefox 63 compatibility */
  scrollbar-color: rgb(210,210,210) rgb(46,54,69);
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}
```

[github](https://github.com/Aris-t2/CustomCSSforFx/issues/160)

Answer (score 0):

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title></title>
</head>
<style>body {
        scrollbar-width: none; /* For Firefox */
        overflow-y: scroll; 
    }
    
    body::-webkit-scrollbar {
        display: none;
    }</style>
<body>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>
<p>keep scrolling</p>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: @AK Asraful Zaid does this resolves your problem??

Comment: @AK Asraful Zaid let us know if you found this solution helpful...

Answer (score 0):

The prefix `-webkit-` implies that the CSS Rule is for Browsers based on Webkit, e.g. safari. There are a lot of CSS Rules that are for Firefox too, but these prefixes start with  `-moz-`.

but in this case you don't need a prefix.
A simple `scrollbar-width: thin;` should work (FF only):
[check MDN Web Docs for more details](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars#browser_compatibility)