# Remove scroll bar while keeping scroll functionality

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

I need to remove the scroll bar in my site.

But when I use `overflow: hidden` my page won't scroll anymore. Is there any other solution?

I couldn't find one with Google.

Comment: On which element you are using this property?

Comment: Body. Answer from Mike does work, but not in all browsers...

Comment: posted my answer please check.

Answer (score 2):

I have tried to use overflow:hidden; but it does exactly what you said.. So you should try to add this to your css.

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar{
    display: none;
}
```

Comment: But how about the other browser like IE and FF?

Comment: This works in Chrome. But indeed, how about in IE and other browsers?

Comment: Yes.. This only works in Chrome. There hasn't been any other solutions for other browsers yet. So I think you should stick to JQuery. I've found an other thread related to this one. You should check it out.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox

Comment: Hmm. I have found something else. The parent div has a width of 150px and overflow: hidden;. The div inside the parent has a width that exceeds the width of the parent. Because of the overflow: hidden, you won't see the scrollingbar. Maybe this helps:  http://jsfiddle.net/qqPcb/

Answer (score 1):

elementary than you can hide an element on the page is to assign `display: none; or visability: hidden;`

Even invisible elements take up space on the page. Use the "display" property to create invisible elements that do not take up space!

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there is a cross-browser solution to hide the scrollbar while preserving scroll functionality.

Although, you can easily simulate this behaviour, with help from a full-body wrapper that takes on the dimensions of the body but is padded on the right to hide the scrollbar.

Yes, you must give the `overflow:hidden` property to body, but your wrapper becomes your new scrollable element. Something like the following should work for you:

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrapper">Lots of text.....</div>
```

**CSS**

```
html{
    height:100%;
}
body{
    margin:0;
    overflow:hidden;
    height:100%;
}
#wrapper{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    padding-right:20px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/fKT4g/)

Answer (score 0):

Try :

```
Overflow : auto
```

if scroll is required, it will display automatically.

You can also try

```
Overflow-X : auto
Overflow-Y : auto
```

Let me know if this fixes your problem.

Answer (score 0):

If you need to remove the scrollbar you can use these property. please check and share if works for you. check the **[DEMO](http://jsbin.com/kenosusa/1/edit)**.

```
#container{
    width:100%;
    height:100%;
    overflow:auto;
    position:fixed;
    padding-right:20px; /*will give a Illusion of removing the scrollbar because browser scrollbar width is 20px*/
}
```

Comment: I see. But now you are using overflow: hidden. That results i a page without scrollbar. But the site is also not able to scroll anymore.

Comment: its very hard to resolve the problem unless we see any code.. Everyone can make a assumption only here.

Comment: seems @oGeez have given the right solution. and I hope that solution you are looking for..