# How can I create custom scrollbar for Mozilla Firefox with CSS?

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar

Is it possible to create a custom scrollbar for Mozilla Firefox with CSS?

I found some articles which tells it was supported in past (e.g. http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/).

Are there more examples?

Comment: The only viable solution for custom scrollbars across multiple browsers is Javascript, I usually use and recommend this plugin:

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Comment: BEST SOLUTION https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/noiascrollbars/ Here is the best sollution

Comment: I would like to recommend [`fakescroll`](https://github.com/yairEO/fakescroll) which is a vanilla-js tiny script for custom scrollbars

Comment: Starting from Firefox 64 you can use the `scrollbar-color` property: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-color

Answer (score 18, accepted):

On this side the firefox scollbar is cancelled.

http://codemug.com/html/custom-scrollbars-using-css/

But look here:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com

http://hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar

http://script-tutorials.com/custom-scrollbars-cross-browser-solution

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller

These are plugins that work for all browsers.

Plugin only for firefox:
https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/noiascrollbars/

I hope I could help you!

Comment: This is the best answer I have come across on this issue. @dabraham, consider accepting this answer. http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller is perfect: at least for me. All other solutions I explored from google results came with many tiny issues.

Comment: these are all javascript solutions, and not css as requested

Comment: @alwe It is NOT possible with css for Mozilla Firefox: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790