# How to hide the vertical scrollbar in the HTML page but scroll in the div

Tags: html, css

I am using the following code "`::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none;}`" , it is working in google chrome but not supported by **Firefox**. How to hide the vertical scrollbar in **Firefox** is there any alternative code.

Comment: Why don't you try `overflow-y:hidden`..?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/6165489/3419997

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)

Answer (score 1):

You can use `overflow-y: hidden`. This will hide the vertical scrollbar.

Ref: http://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_pos_overflow.asp