# -moz- prefix for scrollbar not working in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, vendor-prefix

I am trying to change scrollbar style. it is working in chrome and opera but not working in firefox.

my code for webkit look like this :

```
body::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

body::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 7px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;

}

body::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #2CC185;  
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%,
                                              transparent 25%,
                                              transparent 50%,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
                                              transparent 75%,
                                              transparent)
}
```

and for mozilla like this :

```
body::-moz-scrollbar-track
{
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 1px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

body::-moz-scrollbar
{
    width: 7px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;

}

body::-moz-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #2CC185;  
    background-image: -moz-linear-gradient(45deg,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%,
                                              transparent 25%,
                                              transparent 50%,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
                                              transparent 75%,
                                              transparent)
}
```

it is not working for firefox any Idea please.

Comment: Please see: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox