# how to change browsers default scrollbar using css or jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css, scrollbar

How to replace custom style scrollbar with default browser's scrollbar (i can able to change in chrome using webkit)

```
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, .4);
    background-color: #CFCFCF
}
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #2C3E50
}
```

But i want to change in mozilla firefox too.. Help me pls

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using CSS you can only style the webkit's scrollbar.

If you want a cross browser solution you can use the following plugin:

http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/

or you can choose any from the list given on the following link:

http://www.sitepoint.com/10-jquery-custom-scrollbar-plugins/

Answer (score 0):

#### Using jQuery

Try this pluggin : [jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/fullpage_scroll.html)

#### Using CSS

There's no Firefox (Gecko) equivalent to `::-webkit-scrollbar`

You'll have to stick with jQuery.

Plenty of people would like this feature, see: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790

This report is asking for the *exact* same thing you're asking for: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=547260

Sorce Answer: [Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)