# Custom scrollbar on firefox

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, css

I need custom scrollbar on my website but i dont know how to  do it.
Something like this: https://source.nbot.eu/.
I alredy tried something but nothing happend.

Thanks!

Comment: Have you tried nicescroll.min.js ?

Comment: Possible Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox

Comment: I will use nicescroll, thanks for all :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The scrollbar bugs are already open in Firefox's ToDo list in [BugZilla](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=77790). So technically this is not possible unless you use a JavaScript based solution like [`NiceScroll JS`](http://areaaperta.com/nicescroll/).

To use NiceScroll JS, you need to include the script:

```
<script src="jquery.nicescroll.js"></script>
```

And activate it:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
  $("html").niceScroll();
});
```