# how to make this css compatible in Firefox browser

Tags: html, css

This is my CSS for the custom style scroll-bar its works fine in chrome but not in Firefox browser.

how to make this CSS compatible in Firefox browser

```
 <style>
    .scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }
    .scroll::-webkit-scrollbar {
    height: 6px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    }
    .scroll::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    background-color: #000000;
    border-radius:10px;
    }
</style>
```

Comment: Firefox uses `-moz-` where some other broswers including chrome use `-webkit-`.

Comment: Notice your use of `-webkit-*`? There are [other prefixes for different browsers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Glossary/Vendor_Prefix).

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox

Comment: i used -moz- but its not working.................

Answer (score 0):

Firefox scollbar style customization doesn’t work any more.

But you can try plugins that works in all browser.

[Jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com)

[Hesido](http://hesido.com/web.php?page=customscrollbar)

http://script-tutorials.com/custom-scrollbars-cross-browser-solution

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller

And also you can try below plugin only for firefox.

[Noiascrollbars](https://addons.mozilla.org/de/firefox/addon/noiascrollbars/)

hope this information helps you.