# How to write css for webkit scrollbar using javascript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a div called 'dynamic' with some text in it and I am adding style to it using javascript

```
var styleElement = document.createElement("style");
styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("#dynamic { color: red; }"));
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleElement);
```

It works fine. Same way, I am trying to add some css for scrollbar and we can achieve it by the css code below:

```
div ::-webkit-scrollbar {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    width: 7px;
}

div ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 4px;
    background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
}
```

So, now I added it using javascript like this:

```
var styleElement = document.createElement("style");
styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("
     div ::-webkit-scrollbar{
        -webkit-appearance: none;
         width: 7px;
     }
     div ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
         border-radius: 4px;
         background-color: rgba(0,0,0,.5);
         -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);
     }
"));
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleElement);
```

But this is not working as expected.

My question is:

For first scenario, it was working fine (adding color to "dynamic" div using javascript), But for second scenario, if I add css for scrollbar using javascript, its not working. If first scenario works, then the second scenario should also work.

So, whether I written wrongly or is there any other way to add css for webkit-scrollbar using javascript?

Here is the code [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/x3yz13c5/)

Answer (score 1):

> if I add css for scrollbar using javascript, its not working

The problem isn't caused by the javascript and the style should be appended to the head tag in any js enabled browsers.

The Pseudo `::-webkit-scrollbar` should work for webkit browers but not for Firefox (Gecko). Another similar thread can be found here [Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox).

Try running the code snippet below, also see the color of the scrollbar.

```js
var styleElement = document.createElement("style");
styleElement.appendChild(document.createTextNode("div ::-webkit-scrollbar {-webkit-appearance: none;width: 7px;}div ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {border-radius: 4px;background-color: rgba(250,0,0,.5);-webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 1px rgba(255,255,255,.5);}"));
document.getElementsByTagName("head")[0].appendChild(styleElement);
```

```css
#container{
    width:500px;
    height:300px;
    background-color:#E0E0E0;
    position:relative;
}
#draggable{
    width:300px;
    height:200px;
    left:10px;
    top:20px;
    background-color:white;
    position:absolute;
    overflow:scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
   <div id="draggable">Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum."But I must explain to you how all this mistaken idea of denouncing pleasure and praising pain was born and I will give you a complete account of the system, and expound the actual teachings of the great explorer of the truth, the master-builder of human happiness. No one rejects, dislikes, or avoids pleasure itself, because it is pleasure, but because those who do not know how to pursue pleasure rationally encounter consequences that are extremely painful. Nor again is there anyone who loves or pursues or desires to obtain pain of itself, because it is pain, but because occasionally circumstances occur in which toil and pain can procure him some great pleasure. To take a trivial example, which of us ever undertakes laborious physical exercise, except to obtain some advantage from it? But who has any right to find fault with a man who chooses to enjoy a pleasure that has no annoying consequences, or one who avoids a pain that produces no resultant pleasure?"</div>
</div>
```

Comment: @Thinker The answer's been updated, try running the code snippet.