# Scroll-bar not show the same style in Firefox as Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, css, google-chrome

Is there any idea to make **Scroll-bar** support in **Chrome** and **Firefox**?

I really want to use **CSS** or **CSS3** but when I search, I saw only this code :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
width: 15px;
height: 15px;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track-piece  {
background-color: #C2D2E4;
}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:vertical {
height: 30px;
background-color: #0A4C95;}
```

It works perfectly only on **Chrome**.

How can I do the same thing for **Firefox**?

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, but there is no Firefox equivalent. You'd have to use something like a jQuery plugin to get the same scrollbars to non-webkit based browsers.

Something like this may help you:
http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

Comment: I have used this but if I set div to height:100% it not working

Comment: Whilst that's a slightly separate issue, if you can get a jfiddle to show that problem, I can see if I can get it working for you.

Answer (score 1):

Sorry there is no option. These are not meant to be edited I'm afraid. Your only solution to support multiple browsers would be JavaScript or a jQuery library to do this more consistently. Its the same issue with some other elements like select option dropdowns and that can be overcome in the same way using a library called Chosen.js. 
I'm sure a quick google should bring up a couple of solutions that do enough of what you need.
Try :- http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/