# Is there any way to have custom scrollbar using css only in Firefox?? I found this for chrome but not for Firefox

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar

I want a custome scrollbar for my website, I found this for chrome, but not for firefox. I dont want to use heavy jQuery plugins, Is that possible to do this with css only? 
CSS I found for Chrome:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
        width: 12px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
        border-radius: 10px;
    }

    ::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
        border-radius: 10px;
        -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    }
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

Not possible through CSS in Firefox (and most other browsers). However there's the possibility to style scrollbars in XUL apps (add-ons for Firefox, for instance).

Answer (score 0):

Firefox does not support this feature anymore.
Check this bug report:

https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=547260

Answer (score 0):

Through css if somehow you reach for firefox then IE and safari also going to create issue.better use jquery plugin for scroll bar

Answer (score 0):

Since Firefox version 64 you can use the following [two css properties](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/scrollbar-width) to provide style and color to the scrollbar.

scrollbar-width
scrollbar-color

```css
.scrollable {
    scrollbar-width: thin;
    scrollbar-color: #3487ab #efefef;
}

.scrollable {
  background-color: #a3d5d3;
  height: 100%;
  overflow-y: auto;
  width: 240px;
  height: 120px;
}
```

```html
  <div class="scrollable">
    <div>Item 1</div>
    <div>Item 2</div>
    <div>Item 3</div>
    <div>Item 4</div>
    <div>Item 5</div>
    <div>Item 6</div>
    <div>Item 7</div>
    <div>Item 8</div>
    <div>Item 9</div>
  </div>
```