# Css scrollbar not working in firefox

Tags: css, firefox, webkit, scrollbar

I use -webkit-scrollbar CSS code, which works well for Safari and Chrome:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { width: 5px; }
::-webkit-scrollbar-button {width: 8px;height:5px;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {background:none;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {background:#000;}
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {background:#000;}
```

How can I do the same thing for Firefox? (I don't want using JQuery)

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/q/7725652/3345375

Comment: Also: http://stackoverflow.com/q/35772559/3345375