# Styling scrollbar on firefox

Tags: css, firefox

I have styled scrollbar of element on chrome using

```
aside::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    color: skyblue;
}
aside::-moz-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
    color: skyblue;
}
aside::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}
aside::-moz-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}
aside::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
aside::-moz-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
aside::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: skyblue;
}
aside::-moz-scrollbar-thumb{
    background: skyblue;
}
```

as I tried to implement same thing on Firefox I found out Mozilla no more supports old styling scrollbar method...

Is there any way to style a scrollbar in Firefox now?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

not possible with css

you can try [jscrollpane](http://jscrollpane.kelvinluck.com/)

Answer (score 0):

**In my experience not possible** to that.We have to add some plugings for that.

Please refer this link: [Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)