# HTML CSS , table TH and TD are not in same line

Tags: html, css, css-tables, smart-table

Open below link seems that TH and TD are not in same line. The reason might be because of the scroll bar. How to resolve this issue so that even with scroll TD and TH will in same line?

```
table {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    align-items: stretch;
    height: 500px; /* this can vary */
}
```

https://plnkr.co/edit/fcdXKE?p=preview

[image]

Comment: Have you tried my edited answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Getting the offset of the `th`, comparing it to the offset of the `td`, and then setting the `margin-left` property of the `th` as the difference of those two should work.

[Tested Demo](https://plnkr.co/edit/TWCXARPlo4MQ6TNVGpfI?p=preview):

```
// set id on table
var dataTable = document.getElementById("dataTable");
var tableHead = dataTable.getElementsByTagName("thead")[0];
var headRow = tableHead.getElementsByTagName("tr")[0];
var tds = document.querySelectorAll('#dataTable tbody td');
var ths = document.querySelectorAll('#dataTable thead th');
for(i=0;i<tds.length;i++){
    var offset=tds[i].offsetLeft- ths[i].offsetLeft;
    var thToSet = headRow.getElementsByTagName("th")[i];
    thToSet.style.marginLeft = offset + "px";
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The scrollbar in the `tbody` is reducing his width, while `thead`doesn't have one.

That's why 20% width in the thead doesn't match the 20% width in the tbody.

You could set a padding on the `tr` in the `thead` but i'm not sure it will be cross-browser...

You could also use this for the browsers supporting webkit ([CanIUse](http://caniuse.com/#feat=css-scrollbar)) :

```
::-webkit-scrollbar { 
    display: none; 
}
```

For Firefox, there is no way to custom it with CSS, you will have to deal with jQuery (see [thirtydot](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6165489/3077606)'s answer for more informations).
There are librarie making good looking scrollbar : [Custom Content Scroller](http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/)