# HTML and enable div's horizontal scrolling but hide the horizontal scrollbar

Tags: html, css

I need my div to be scrollable. Now it works fine, but I would like to hide the horizontal scrollbar. I do not want to disable it, just hide it.

All I want to see is one vertical scrollbar on the browser window. No horizontal scrollbars on the screen.

No JavaScript/jQuery allowed. I need a cross-browser solution.

```css
#kaaviopohja {
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: yellow;
}

#kaaviotaulukko {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  background-color: pink;
}
```

```html
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br />
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br />
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br />
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br />
hhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhhh<br />

<DIV id="kaaviopohja">

  <div id="kaaviotaulukko" style="white-space: nowrap; position: relative; text-align: center;">
    <div style="display:inline-block">
      <!--
        -->
      <DIV STYLE="DISPLAY:INLINE-BLOCK">
        <div style="float:left;width:0">
          <div id="navi7">
            <div style="z-index:100;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;bottom:0;max-height:1em;margin:auto;">A</div>
            <div style="z-index:100;position:fixed;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;max-height:1em;margin:auto;">B</div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="krs" style="display: inline-block; vertical-align: top; width: 300px;">
          <div>
            <h3>LQsssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssssss</h3>
          </div>
          1<br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br /> 1
          <br />2<br />3<br />4<br />5<br />6<br />7<br />8<br />9<br />10<br />
        </div>
      </DIV>
      <!--
        -->
      <div style="float: right; width: 0;">
        <div id="navi100">
          <div style="z-index: 100; position: fixed; left: 0; top: 500px">C</div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <!--

      -->
      <div style="z-index:99;width:70px;position:fixed;left:0;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;background-color:red;"><br />
      </div>

      <div style="z-index:99;width:70px;position:fixed;right:0;top:0;bottom:0;margin:auto;background-color:red;"><br />
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

</DIV>
```

Comment: What's creating the horizontal scrollbar? I don't see one.

Comment: Please take a look now.

Comment: You want the overflowing text to be hidden and you can't scroll to it? Or you want it to break so you can see the rest of the text without having to scroll?

Comment: If I scroll horizontally with my mouse wheel, I want to see the rest of the text. The text cannot be wrapped.

Comment: So you want to scroll, you just want the scrollbar to be hidden? Pretty sure that's impossible.

Comment: @MichaelCoker This is my best try so far: [link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44374054/5833180)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a similar question [Hide scroll bar, but still being able to scroll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-still-being-able-to-scroll), but I believe your question is focused on the horizontal scrollbar. In that other question, I found something that can help you, this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41021131/6178243). Jean posted that answer where he puts `margin-bottom: -17px;` in the container's child to hide the scrollbar.I did a simple [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/7h9gw6f7/4/) to ilustrate his technique. It's a hack to hide the scrollbar, I didn't check if this work on all major browses but it works on chrome and firefox.

Answer (score 0):

You can use CSS properties for this.

```
overflow-x: hidden; /* hide horizontal scrollbar */
overflow-y: scroll; /* show vertical scrollbar */
```

Comment: If I use `overflow-x: hidden;` then the div is not scrollable horizontally. In other words, that is not want I want.

Comment: doesn't it scroll with arrows when being the active element? Edit: no, it doesn't - ignore this.

Comment: or do you want the scrollbar to be transparent but still draggable?

Comment: Yes, horizontal scrollbar needs to be transparent or invisible. With all browsers.

Comment: this (https://jsfiddle.net/btvvfjbp/) should work with Chrome but I think that Firefox doesn't have the equivalent.. (according to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

I just modified my CSS code. This seems to help:

```
#kaaviotaulukko {
  width: 100%;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  padding-bottom: 17px;
  background-color: pink;

  margin-top: -17px; /* this was added */
  top: 17px; /* this was added */
}
```