# Hiding the vertical scrollbar in all browsers

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

In the below code, I want to hide the scrollbar of the first block (**div1**) without using `overflow` property in all the browsers.

Any suggestions would be helpful.

**Fiddle:**
http://jsfiddle.net/mvn1ngby/12/

```js
$('#div1').scroll(function(){
    $('#div2').scrollTop( $('#div1').scrollTop() );
});

$('#div2').scroll(function(){
    $('#div1').scrollTop( $('#div2').scrollTop() );
});
```

```css
div.outer {
    display:inline-block;
    width:150px;
    height:320px;
    border:1px solid black;
    overflow-y:auto;
}

div.outer > div {
    height:3000px;
}
#div1 div {
  width:300px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer" id="div1">
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
<div class="outer" id="div2">
    <div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Why you wont use overflow property? I think with something like this ::-webkit-scrollbar { display: none;} for example

Comment: check this one https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16670931/hide-scroll-bar-but-while-still-being-able-to-scroll

Comment: @SilverSurfer @HD using `webkit` prefix would work for only some browsers.

Comment: @HiteshMisro Is just and example for webkit like Chrome or Opera, he can put the rest of browsers

Comment: Is this the effect you want? http://jsfiddle.net/ync1akbz/1/

Comment: @ovokuro seems like you have done it.. let me check!

Comment: Oh, I found this, there isnt option for webkit scrollbar in firefox https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox

Comment: @ovokuro thats close but scrolling isn't working on the left block by using that `overflow` property.

Comment: @SilverSurfer ya it will work only for `webkit` browsers.

Comment: Do you want to control the scrolling yourself that is why you are hiding the scrollbar? You can't actually escape the fact the scrollbar appear because the child has more height than its container and hide the scrollbar without using `overflow` unless you make that `child element position absolute` then control its position to behave like it is scrolling.

Comment: @HiteshMisro ah ok I see... Maybe Felix Mosheev answer will help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is a hack but works.
The idea is to pull the area of the scroll-bar outside of the view port.

The "pull" size suppose to be with the width of the scroll bar, usually the wider one (on Windows)

```js
$('#div1').scroll(function() {
  $('#div2').scrollTop($('#div1').scrollTop());
});

$('#div2').scroll(function() {
  $('#div1').scrollTop($('#div2').scrollTop());
});
```

```css
div.outer {
  display: inline-block;
  overflow: hidden;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

#div1>div,
#div2>div {
  height: 3000px;
}

.scrollable {
  width: 150px;
  height: 320px;
  overflow-y: auto;
}

#div1 {
  margin-right: -25px;
  padding-right: 25px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="scrollable" id="div1">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div class="outer">
  <div class="scrollable" id="div2">
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try to add a new container div with css:

```
.container { width: 100%;}
```

And inside put the *div1, div2*