# Vertical scrollbar styling not works in Firefox browser

Tags: html, css, firefox, scrollbar

Code for Chrome, Opera, Safari for scrollbar as below:

```
.scroll_bar::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 20px;
}
.scroll_bar::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px #0067ab;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
.scroll_bar::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0px 0px 6px #0067ab;
  border-radius: 5px;
}
```

And what I should do for Firefox?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)

Comment: It seems that Firefox doesn't support CSS custom scrollbars, you can make use of javascript though.

Comment: @Highdef I search also for that. But don't need any library for that.

Answer (score 0):

would you like to use this.

[custom scroll bar using js](https://gromo.github.io/jquery.scrollbar/demo/basic.html)

Answer (score 0):

There is a solution to your problem on [**Mozilla Searchfox**](https://searchfox.org/mozilla-central/source/toolkit/themes/mobile/global/scrollbars.css).

```
scrollbar[orient='vertical'] {
  margin-left: -4px;
  margin-top: 1px;
  min-width: 3px;
  max-width: 3px;
}

scrollbar[orient='vertical'] thumb {
  max-width: 3px !important;
  min-width: 3px !important;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

[Here you can see it on css tricks](https://css-tricks.com/forums/topic/css-tags-for-mozilla-browser-to-style-scrollbar/)
Just change use -moz instead of -webkit

Comment: It's not supported by Firefox.

Comment: **It's not supported in FireFox at the moment**. I wish you have read the contemplate conversation in the link you offered, at the end of that it has been stated that there is no CSS solution to make FireFox to support it at the moment, maybe in near future there will be.