# How to change scroll bar for specific div element?

Tags: html, css

So, the question is how we can set the custom `scrollbar` color for some `div` scroll? I try next, but it does not help, no result:

```
.message-list__container::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

.message-list__container::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.message-list__container::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

This is work, but for browser scroll, not for `div` scroll:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 12px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3); 
    border-radius: 10px;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
}
```

Comment: [dev.mozilla has example at bottom of page](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar)

Comment: @GolezTrol it does not work in Chrome

Comment: Their example does work for me in Chrome, so it should be possible. Can you make an example that includes your HTML, so we can reproduce the issue? You can make a [Stack snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/269753/feedback-requested-runnable-code-snippets-in-questions-and-answers) (runnable code) in the question, and optionally add a JSFiddle, so we can verify the issue in your actual code.

Comment: That does work, the problem could be in the markup.

Comment: It works on chrome. https://jsfiddle.net/michaelyuen/s9k9amf5/ But I suggest other approach for browser compatibility https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox