# Custom scrollbar styling for firefox

Tags: javascript, css, scrollbar, custom-scrolling

Is there any way to design scrollbar in firefox. In chrome, we have certain scrollbar porperties like -webkit-scrollbar-*.

How to achieve the same in firefox using javascript/css? I want to implement this in ember app!

Comment: This kind of issue is resolved here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox

Answer (score -2):

By the time, Firefox does not support ::-moz-scrollbar-*, so you should use javascript to customize it.

The most recomended plugin is [Perfect-scrollbar](http://utatti.github.io/perfect-scrollbar/). It's very simple to implement it your project.