# How can I force firefox to show scroll bars even when not hovering on the element?

Tags: css, firefox, scroll, scrollbar, overflow

Has anyone come up with a good solution that shows the scrollbar on `overflowY: scroll` and also add custom styling to the scrollbar and track on firefox?

I've tried some jQuery plugins but they don't seem to show the scroll bar even if you're not hovering on the elemen AND be able to have custom styling on the scrollbar.

Example here:
https://codepen.io/hellojessicagraham/pen/vawJOo

Desired result on chrome
Not so desired on Firefox..

On chrome and safari the scroll bars show but on firefox the scroll bar only shows when you hover on the element, also there is no custom styling

What is the cleanest solution for this if there is a "clean" solution

Comment: The reason you don't see custom styling in firefox is because `webkit` is "only" related to chrome and not firefox. The only browser that actually accepts scrollbar styling is chrome. https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)