# Customize mozilla firefox scrollerbar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css

I have use where I want to change the default scroller for my application in mozilla firefox. I tried with `::-moz-scrollbar` but this doesn't help. I tried using scroller plugins but that as well doesn't help me . I am able to achieve my use case in chrome but not in mozilla firefox. I have attached two different scrollers ,one in google chrome and the other in mozilla firefox. I have to achieve the same scroller as of google chrome.[scroller in google chrome for my application](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z52Hu.png) 
 [scroller inmozilla firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BFgR4.png).

Is there any to achieve this use case in mozilla fiefox ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)

Answer (score 0):

You can try `mCustomscrollbar` plugin, he has taught you how to configure and demos.

http://manos.malihu.gr/jquery-custom-content-scroller/

I used this plugin in my previous project, the compatibility is very good, it is easy to configure.

This is the github address
https://github.com/malihu/malihu-custom-scrollbar-plugin

Should be able to meet your needs.

`::-webkit-scrollbar` This is only valid for webkit kernel browsers.
Firefox browser does not provide css to modify the scrollbar api, it can only be modified by javascript

Comment: How this can be used for default scroller which comes as I have not given an overflow property in cs and as the document size increses, the default scroller automatically comes

Comment: @nip_sham Don't need to set "overflow" property in css, Just set a maximum height, then "init" in js, then the document has optional parameters and scrollbar style, provided you reference this JavaScript and css.

Answer (score 0):

I haven't used it myself but I have heard about **perfect-scrollbar** you might to want to give it a try

[perfect-scrollbar](https://github.com/utatti/perfect-scrollbar)