# I want to implement custom scrollbar for firefox

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar

I want to implement custom scrollbar for my website in firefox. 
I added the following lines to my css file & it works for chrome.

Is there a way to do the same for firefox ?

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
  width: 0.5vw;
}

/* Track */
::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
  background: #2a2a2a;
}

/* Handle */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
  background: #c5a47e;
}

/* Handle on hover */
::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb:hover {
  background: #c5a47e;
}
```

What about compatibility edge & internet explorer. Is there a way to implement the same for them ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox