# Problem with the css of the scrollbar in firefox

Tags: html, css, firefox, scrollbar

I am currently building a website and I want it to work well on chrome, IE10 and firefox. However, I have the problem that the scrollbar in firefox has the standard design because the command *::-webkit-scrollbar* ([Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/::-webkit-scrollbar)) does not work. However, I would like to achieve the same design as in Chrome **without a third-party library**. This includes defining the exact height, width and colors of the scroll bar.
Maybe someone knows a solution how it is possible to get all these functions in firefox?

Thanks in advance

Comment: here are the actual possible option about scrollbars in firefox : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars  it follows https://drafts.csswg.org/css-scrollbars-1/ (w3c draft - CSS scrollbar Module Level 1 )

Comment: @G-Cyr So does it accept custom scrollbars?

Comment: @EvikGhazarian color and thickness can be customized as commented on mozilla site. try it yourself ;)  here an example playing with scale() to mimic also a thin scrollbar anywhere transform is supported. https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/details/ydZPrL

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As of late 2018, there is now limited customization available in Firefox!

See these answers:

- [https://stackoverflow.com/a/54101063/405015](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53739309/405015)
- https://stackoverflow.com/a/53739309/405015

And this for background info: https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1460109