# jQuery Nice Select with scroll bar

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am very glad to use this wonderful library - jQuery Nice Select [link](https://jqueryniceselect.hernansartorio.com/).
But i cant understand why this not support scroll bar especially in google chrome

Chrome :

[image]

And Firefox

[image]

I can't understand why google chrome doesn't support scroll bar or I should add it somehow?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This isn't related to Firefox or Chrome. You may just be looking at the browsers with different viewports.

In any case, you need to add this to your CSS to add a scrollbar:

```
.list {
  max-height: 100px; // or whatever the height you want
  overflow-y: scroll !important;
}
```

Source: tested it myself in both Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: You need to add it to `.list`, not `select`. Nice Select creates a `<div>` from your code that contains a `<ul class="list">` inside of it. This is the DOM object that you want to modify with CSS.

Comment: ye i think it should be  `.nice-select .list` in my nice select css?

Comment: Don't modify the nice select class, if you update nice select it will delete this code. Put in a separate CSS file or your own CSS file. Just make sure you put `overflow-y: scroll !important;`. The `!important` part will override nice select's CSS.

Comment: and it should have same name

Comment: It doesn't have to be the same name, you just reference the other CSS file in your HTML Head section. So like `<link href="other.css" rel="stylesheet">`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/227816/discussion-between-thomas-yamakaitis-and-nikola-marinov).

Answer (score 2):

I know this is a kind of late, but the accepted answer didn't work for me. I had to use the code below to make it work (maybe for a newer version of library):

```
    .nice-select-dropdown .list {
        height: 100% !important;
        max-height: 100% !important;
        overflow: auto !important;
    }
    
    .nice-select.open .nice-select-dropdown {
        max-height: 240px; /*or whatever height you want*/
        overflow-y: auto;
        overflow-x: hidden;
    }
```

Answer (score -2):

Try this out...

**NOTE: This hides the scrollbar, so some people who prefer scrollbars over gestures  may have some trouble accessing your site**

```
/* Hide scrollbar for IE, Edge and Firefox */
.example {
  -ms-overflow-style: none;  /* IE and Edge */
  scrollbar-width: none;  /* Firefox */
}
```

Credits w3schools

Comment: but i want to add scroll bar

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox

Comment: This answer is not right. @Nikola is asking to add a scrollbar for a specific library.