# ::-webkit-scrollbar not working on firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css

Firefox Webkit Scroll not working

```
.services::-webkit-scrollbar {
     width: 2px;
     height: 2px;
}
```

Note:- Please suggest some way to resolve this issue as soon as possible.

How to resolve this issue using JS/css??

Comment: Because it is *-webkit-* scrollbar...

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this, it will definitely work

```
scroll-snap-type: mandatory;
scrollbar-width: none;
```

Answer (score 1):

Firefox IS NOT a WebKit browser... Therefore, a vendor prefix for Webkit browsers (Chrome, Edge, Safari) isn't going to have any effect on Firefox's rendering.

I highly recommend you add something like [Autoprefixer](https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer) to your build pipeline. It will manage adding prefixes where needed, not adding them in places where they're not needed (eg `border-radius`) and let you focus on writing standards-compliant CSS. (even though it won't help in this case where you're targeting vendor-specific selectors)

for reference Mozilla based browsers use the prefix `-moz-`

Comment: even though the answer is true, it ignores the most important fact: The `-moz-` prefex wont do anything here as Firefox has very limited support for scrollbar changes aswell as it doesnt need a prefix for that in the first place.

Comment: @tacoshy 100% agree, but you already pointed to good resources for scrollbars. I was hoping if the OP understood why the question was flawed, it would help them search for the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

/// For Firefox ///

```
.section{
   scrollbar-width: thin;
   scrollbar-color: #838383 transparent;
}
```

/// For Chrome ///

```
.section_bar::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 10px;
}
```