# How style Mozilla firefox vertical and horizontal scroll bars

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to get rid of the horizontal and vertical scroll bars using css properties on a project i'm working, but is isn't working and i don't really know how to get rid of it. Anyhelp from here, really need it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use:

```
:root{
/*scrollbar-color: thumb-color track-color*/
scrollbar-color:#661ca3 #181818;
scrollbar-width:thin;
}
```

**OR**

```
html{
scrollbar-color:#661ca3 #181818;
scrollbar-width:thin;
}
```

**OR**  [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox#6165489) , also, might help you.