# Problems with changing the scrollbar appearance in firefox

Tags: html, css, scrollbar

**Hello!**

I put this into my css file for changing the look of the scrollbar.
It works in nearly every browser as intended, but not in firefox:

```
::-webkit-scrollbar{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #f1f1f1;
}

::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb{
    background-color: #353b48;
}
```

What do I need to make in work in Firefox too? ^^

Answer (score 0):

The `::-webkit-scrollbar` selector is not supported in Firefox:

https://caniuse.com/?search=%3A%3A-webkit-scrollbar

You can still customize the scrollbar though!  See these:

[Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox/54101063#54101063)

[Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox/53739309#53739309)

Comment: Thank you for the fast answer, but as I read what you linked it seems like their is not the same amount of customization possible, but I will try my best to make it good :D

Answer (score 0):

Firefox doesn't support "-webkit-scrollbar", but it still supports a custom scrollbar.

```
scrollbar-color: #f1f1f1 white;
scrollbar-width: thin;
```

Just add that to your code.

[Source](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars)

Comment: That don't really work. I tried it, but I want the scrollbar for the whole site and that's only for the div with the text. I am pretty new to "coding" too, but when I give as example the <html> the class or make a div inside it that doesn't work either :o