# Styling Firefox scrollbar

Tags: css, firefox, scrollbar, tailwind-css

i'm trying to style Firefox's scrollbar without any success.
I think it's good to mention that i'm working with tailwind.
I've tried the following :

```
::-moz-scrollbar-thumb{
  scrollbar-color: red;
} 

 html{
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: red;
} 

.scroller::-moz-scrollbar-thumb {
  height: 30px;
  background-color: #0A4C95;
} 

 .scroller {
  width: 300px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
  scrollbar-color: rebeccapurple green;
  scrollbar-width: thin;
}

 body{
  scrollbar-width: thin;
  scrollbar-color: red !important
```

But there's no change. is it possible to style it?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox)

Answer (score 2):

Did you check this answer [Custom CSS Scrollbar for Firefox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox/53739309#53739309)?

Plus, I found [this](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Scrollbars) in `Mozilla Developer` website and it's working for me.

Comment: For some reason the color property works yet the width doesn't. the width setting only works on the dev tools yet not in the app itself. even when i add !important

Comment: Seems like you can't set width to a pixel value, only the values thin, auto or none

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, custom scrollbar is not fully supported by Firefox browser. why?
I don't know. to help see that, please [open this link](https://codepen.io/GhostRider/pen/oNvoNv) in Firefox then opera and chrome.

I did and on firefox, there was no custom scrollbar, but in other browsers, I saw them all.

there might be an advanced way to do it. good luck.

```css
header
{
    font-family: 'Lobster', cursive;
    text-align: center;
    font-size: 25px;    
}

#info
{
    font-size: 18px;
    color: #555;
    text-align: center;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

a{
    color: #074E8C;
}

.scrollbar
{
    margin-left: 30px;
    float: left;
    height: 300px;
    width: 65px;
    background: #F5F5F5;
    overflow-y: scroll;
    margin-bottom: 25px;
}

.force-overflow
{
    min-height: 450px;
}

#wrapper
{
    text-align: center;
    width: 500px;
    margin: auto;
}

/*
 *  STYLE 1
 */

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-1::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #555;
}

/*
 *  STYLE 2
 */

#style-2::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-2::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-2::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,.3);
    background-color: #D62929;
}

/*
 *  STYLE 3
 */

#style-3::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-3::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 6px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-3::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #000000;
}

/*
 *  STYLE 4
 */

#style-4::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-4::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-4::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #000000;
    border: 2px solid #555555;
}


/*
 *  STYLE 5
 */

#style-5::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-5::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-5::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #0ae;
    
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear, 0 0, 0 100%,
                       color-stop(.5, rgba(255, 255, 255, .2)),
                       color-stop(.5, transparent), to(transparent));
}


/*
 *  STYLE 6
 */

#style-6::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-6::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-6::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #F90; 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(45deg,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%,
                                              transparent 25%,
                                              transparent 50%,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
                                              transparent 75%,
                                              transparent)
}


/*
 *  STYLE 7
 */

#style-7::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#style-7::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-7::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,
                                       left bottom,
                                       left top,
                                       color-stop(0.44, rgb(122,153,217)),
                                       color-stop(0.72, rgb(73,125,189)),
                                       color-stop(0.86, rgb(28,58,148)));
}

/*
 *  STYLE 8
 */

#style-8::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    border: 1px solid black;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-8::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-8::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #000000;  
}


/*
 *  STYLE 9
 */

#style-9::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-9::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-9::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #F90; 
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 25%,
                                              transparent 25%,
                                              transparent 50%,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 50%,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, .2) 75%,
                                              transparent 75%,
                                              transparent)
}


/*
 *  STYLE 10
 */

#style-10::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#style-10::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-10::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #AAA;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,
                                              rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 25%,
                                              transparent 25%,
                                              transparent 50%,
                                              rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 50%,
                                              rgba(0, 0, 0, .2) 75%,
                                              transparent 75%,
                                              transparent)
}


/*
 *  STYLE 11
 */

#style-11::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.3);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#style-11::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-11::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #3366FF;
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(0deg,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 25%,
                                              transparent 25%,
                                              transparent 50%,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 50%,
                                              rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5) 75%,
                                              transparent 75%,
                                              transparent)
}

/*
 *  STYLE 12
 */

#style-12::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #444444;
}

#style-12::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-12::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #D62929;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,
                                              transparent,
                                              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 50%,
                                              transparent,
                                              transparent)
}

/*
 *  STYLE 13
 */

#style-13::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.9);
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#style-13::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 12px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-13::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #D62929;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,
                                              transparent,
                                              rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.4) 50%,
                                              transparent,
                                              transparent)
}

/*
 *  STYLE 14
 */

#style-14::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.6);
    background-color: #CCCCCC;
}

#style-14::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-14::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(90deg,
                                              rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 0%,
                                              rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 25%,
                                              transparent 100%,
                                              rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 75%,
                                              transparent)
}

/*
 *  STYLE 15
 */

#style-15::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#style-15::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-15::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: -webkit-gradient(linear,
                                       40% 0%,
                                       75% 84%,
                                       from(#4D9C41),
                                       to(#19911D),
                                       color-stop(.6,#54DE5D))
}

/*
 *  STYLE 16
 */

#style-16::-webkit-scrollbar-track
{
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.1);
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

#style-16::-webkit-scrollbar
{
    width: 10px;
    background-color: #F5F5F5;
}

#style-16::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb
{
    border-radius: 10px;
    background-color: #FFF;
    background-image: -webkit-linear-gradient(top,
                                              #e4f5fc 0%,
                                              #bfe8f9 50%,
                                              #9fd8ef 51%,
                                              #2ab0ed 100%);
}
```

```html
  <div id="wrapper">
    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-default">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-1">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-2">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-3">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-4">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-5">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-6">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-7">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-8">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-9">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-10">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-11">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-13">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-14">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="scrollbar" id="style-15">
      <div class="force-overflow"></div>
    </div>
```