# How much can you customize the Scrollbar CSS in Firefox?

Tags: css, google-chrome, firefox, scrollbar

I'm making a transition from Chrome to Firefox, but I'm having some trouble adjusting because I have been making a personal website for a while and the scrollbar CSS not fitting my design is just really bothering me

[Here's what the scrollbars look like between browsers](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oCDUR.png)

On the left is how it looks on Chrome and the design I'm going for

On the right is how it appears on Firefox

I've read around that the scrollbar customization on Firefox is extremely limited and I was wondering if there are any ways around it? Alternatively, aside from the width and the main two colours, how much can you actually customize with Firefox?

This is what the regular scrollbar CSS looks like on Chrome

```
*::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 15px;
}

*::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border: 2px solid #0c091a;
    background: linear-gradient(180deg, #ff00ff, #00ffff);
    border-radius: 7px;
}
*::-webkit-scrollbar-track {
    background: #0c091a;
    border: 2px solid #0c091a;
    border-radius: 7px;
}
```

Comment: you can use custom scrollBars...

Comment: scrollbar styling in Firefox is a bit... underwhelming. This should help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6165472/custom-css-scrollbar-for-firefox/54101063#54101063 but don't expect wonders.